# Query documents into JSON format Marklogic

Tags: json, search, marklogic

I want to use a QBE query to get the matched documents first, and save the documents into JSON format. So I use JacksonHandle and JSONDocumentManager. But I cannot get the documents. Here is the code:

```
JSONDocumentManager jdm = databaseClient.newJSONDocumentManager();
StringHandle newHandle = new StringHandle(JSONQuery).withFormat(Format.JSON);
RawQueryByExampleDefinition querydef = queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(newHandle);
JacksonHandle jsonResults = new JacksonHandle();
DocumentPage documents = jdm.search(querydef, 1, jsonResults);
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of this overload of search() gets the search summary instead of the documents.

The DocumentPage iterable provides to the documents.

Does it work to do something along the following lines?

```
JSONDocumentManager jdm = databaseClient.newJSONDocumentManager();
StringHandle newHandle = new StringHandle(JSONQuery).withFormat(Format.JSON);
RawQueryByExampleDefinition querydef =
    queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(newHandle);
DocumentPage page = jdm.search(querydef, 1);
for (DocumentRecord document: page) {
    JacksonHandle documentHandle = document.nextContent​(new JacksonHandle());
    JsonNode documentContent = documentHandle.get();
    // ... operate on the document content ...
}
```

For more information, see:

https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentPage.html

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am confused in the for loop, I cannot call the nextContent method. And seems like you don't use the document defined in the for loop. Should I use document.nextContent()?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in my mockup.  Fixed.